# How to scroll only tbody inside flexbox without using height or sticky?

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox, scroll

I have `table` inside nested `flex` container and I would like to scroll just `tbody`. I don't want to/can't use hardcoded `height` or `max-height` (like for example `500px`) because it should shrink or grow as flebox dictates.

So far I found only the solution using `sticky` on `thead`. It works, but as with all `sticky` approaches scrollbar appears over `thead` as well.

So I am looking for a better solution for scrolling `tbody` -- no `sticky` and no hardcoded `height`.

My sample code which I use for testing:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
<style>
    *
    {
        font-size: 13px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body style="height:100vh;overflow: clip; margin:0;">
<div style="display: flex;height:100%">
<div style="background-color: aqua;">side bar</div>
<div style="flex: 1; display: flex; flex-direction: column">
    <header style="flex : 0 0;"><p style="margin:12px">HEADER BAR</p></header>
   
    <main style="flex: 1 1; min-height:0;display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
        <button style="font-size: 14px;flex:0 0;">+</button>
       
        <div style="overflow: auto; flex:1;">
            <table style="display:contents;">
                <thead style="position:sticky;top:0;background-color: white;">
                <tr>
                    <th>A</th>
                    <th>B</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody style="">
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>12-1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>332-1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>7</td>
                    <td>432-1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>332-1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>7</td>
                    <td>432-1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>332-1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>7</td>
                    <td>432-1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>332-1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>55-1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>end</td>
                    <td>now</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer style="flex:0 0; ">
        <button style="font-size: 14px;">OK</button>
    </footer>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you use table and are looking for only css solution - there is no better solution.